# In a Python for loop, If you define a variable as an element for the for loop, will it overwrite the previous definition?

Tags: python, tkinter

So in this example, although you cant refer anymore to the previous loopRads, python obviously still knows it exist right? That is why when the radiobutton widget is invoked, it functions properly? So basically Python knows which loopRad you're referring to when you clicked on the radiobuttons?

```
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'gold']

def radCall(*args):
    radSel = radVar.get()

    if radSel == 0:
        root.configure(background=colors[0])
    elif radSel == 1:
        root.configure(background=colors[1])
    elif radSel == 2:
        root.configure(background=colors[2])

for col in range(3):
    loopRad = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text=colors[col], variable=radVar, value=col, command=radCall)
    loopRad.grid(row=5, column=col, sticky='w')
```

Comment: Yes because they are all attached to their parent: `root`

Comment: So this is a different story outside of tkinter right?or it is still applicable?

Comment: As long as a reference to your data exists somewhere, it will be valid. If you just create some variable in a for loop, then it won't be accessible elsewhere unless you store/assign it into something else

Comment: So in the case of my example, it was made possible because it was attached to the parent? so outside of tkinter, if for example you want to define a variable inside a for loop, you need to create a variable for each element in the loop?

Comment: Consider [this example](https://repl.it/repls/HoneydewBronzeTutorial). Only the value that was assigned to `a` on the last iteration is preserved. All previous values were overwritten since you are using the same variable name. If you wanted to preserve those values in some sense, you would have appended them to a list for example

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding of for loops that is why I was confused when I saw this code. Because basically the value of loopRad is only the last iteration, so the color should only be gold, but then why is it that it is still functioning properly.  Although I already understand that it is because it was attached to the parent.

Comment: As I said, it's because you are attaching it to `root`

Comment: Yup, I get it now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In `loopRad = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text=colors[col], variable=radVar, value=col, command=radCall)` you have redefined any previous value assigned to `loopRad`. 
Not only that reassignment is the valid one inside the scope of the loop, it will also remain after it.

Furthermore, in Python, even if the variable `loopRad` was never declared before the line `for col in range(3):`, it would be still accessible outside the scope of the loop. That is not the case in some other languages.